# Select Data from 3 tables whereas multiple values should be comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following 3 tables:

[image].......
[image].......
[image]
…………………………           ………………………………                       …………………………

I run the following query

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeId,
  EmployeeName,
  ProjectName
FROM Employee
JOIN ProjEmp
ON Employee.EmployeeId=ProjEmp.EmployeeId
JOIN Project
ON Project.ProjectId=ProjEmp.ProjectId
```

And it gives following result:

[image]

But I need result like this:

[image]

Suggest me the best query for my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to get what you are looking for :

```
WITH CTE AS(SELECT Employee.EmployeeId,
  EmployeeName,
  ProjectName
FROM Employee
JOIN ProjEmp
ON Employee.EmployeeId=ProjEmp.EmployeeId
JOIN Project
ON Project.ProjectId=ProjEmp.ProjectId)

SELECT EmployeeId,EmployeeName,
      ProjectName = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(10),T2.ProjectName)
          FROM CTE T2
          WHERE T1.EmployeeName = T2.EmployeeName
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM CTE T1
GROUP BY EmployeeId,EmployeeName
ORDER BY EmployeeId
```

Result:

```
EMPLOYEEID   EMPLOYEENAME   PROJECTNAME
1            Emp1           ProjA,ProjB
3            Emp3           ProjC
4            Emp4           ProjC,ProjD
5            Emp5           ProjE
7            Emp7           ProjE
8            Emp8           ProjE
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0097/6).